# C++ cannot understand why this code is not thread safe

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

Have created C++ wrapper over some OpenCV functionoanlity and export it for PInvoke, that can call it in parallel.

In nuts:

```
void execute(Document& d) {

            ScriptConfig conf(d);
            Context c(conf);
            OperationManager m;
            while (c.next()) {
                unique_ptr<OperationBase> op = m.create(*c.getCurrentOp()); 
// m.create inside ALWAYS creates unique_ptr<OperationBase>(NEW  ConcreteOperationBase());
//nothing cached
                op->prepare(&c);
                op->execute();  
                op->afterExecute();
            }

        }
```

Internally operations works with it's Context and do some operations in OpenCV. Context holds Mat's instances for operations.

This code is not thread safe. If i try to use several calls of execute emmidiatly they break work of each other on random way. It's looks like operations got invalid in->out mats to work with.

I have check opencv related code in operations to be threadsafe - it's ok.

When i have fix it on following manner:

```
mutex _locker;
```

void execute(Document& d) {

```
            ScriptConfig conf(d);
            Context c(conf);
            OperationManager m;
            while (c.next()) {
                _locker.lock();
                unique_ptr<OperationBase> op = m.create(*c.getCurrentOp()); 
// m.create inside ALWAYS creates unique_ptr<OperationBase>(NEW  ConcreteOperationBase());
//nothing cached
                op->prepare(&c);
                op->execute();  
                op->afterExecute();
                _locker.unlock();
            }

        }
```

No where is no problem with multithread. But this is not that I wanted to get - I have to call operations in parallel!

Comment: can you find out whether different threads use same input/output at the same time? use one mutex per input/output or make sure threads dont share them.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't all your "OperationBase" instances using the same "Context" in parallel?

Comment: this bug not occures in Debug configuration (/MDd) only in Release (/MD)

Answer (score 1):

Some problems was with Mat& that was stored in OperationBase and set with .prepare() method. I'm C# guy so for me "reference" is "shared pointer" not more. I have rewrite all code of OperationBase not to store refs or pointers to mats stored in Context and always get them as Mat* within Operation's method. Such combo became thread safe. )